# React Hooks - useEffect, call fuctions just when I update an specific property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is my useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
        handleFetchUsers();
        handleFetchBooks();
}, [month, listUsers, listBooks]);
```

I want to fetch books and users the first time (and also when the user change the month), and I also need fetch books and user when there are changes outside the component (when cache changes, I want to fech from cache).

The problem here is that there are 3 properties, and when books is updated, the useEffect function dispatch all fetchs, I do not want fetch users if user has not been updated.

Is there a way to fetch books just when books update and fetch uses just when users update?

Right now, I have all fetch duplicated.

I remember in componentWillUpdated, I solve this problem comparing nextProps and currentProps:

```
if(nextProps.users !=== props.users){
  fetchUsers();
}
```

I want a performance like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should!) use useEffect more than once in a functional component. Separate your concerns this way, and you should see the behaviour you are looking for.

```
useEffect(() => {
    handleFetchBooks()
},[month])

useEffect(() => {
    handleFetchUsers()
},[YOUR_USER_DEPENDENCIES])
```

On every rerender react checks the dependencies array and refires the hook if any item has changed, so by keeping them separate you can control this behaviour.

Comment: OMG !

Sorry because I knew useEffect as "componentWillMount" for functions component, I did not think that I could use useEffect more than once. 

Thanks !!! 

This has a lot of sense, sorry if the question was too simply.

Comment: @LeonardoCavani It's one of the tricks of hooks to get used to for sure, once you get the hang of it it becomes very powerful useEffect replaces both componentWillMount and componentWillUpdate, it doesn't work exactly like either, but can fill the role of both if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` was made keeping this in mind, ideally there should be a single task or lets say side effect attached.

So basically just like @Cal Irvine answer, You can have separate effects for your side effects.

```
useEffect(() => {
        taskrelatedtomonthdependant();
}, [month]);

useEffect(() => {
        taskrelatedtouserdependant();
}, [month]);
```